# Pytest does not output junitxml when running in Databricks repo

Tags: python, pytest, databricks

We have a Databricks platform where repos and files in repos are enabled.  As such, we can have .py files within the repos which can be called by Databricks notebooks.

We are currently testing the viability of running our unit tests on Databricks clusters instead of using a (PySpark) image in our Git / CI environment.

The repo within Databricks looks like

```
| - notebook
| - mycode.py
| - mycode_test.py
```

Here, `mycode.py` contains a function that applies a transformation on a Spark Dataframe. The file `mycode_test.py` contains an unit test build with **pytest** (and some fixtures to create test data and handling the Spark session / Spark context).

We run pytest from the notebook, instead of from the command line.  Hence, the Databricks notebook looks like:

```py
import pytest

retcode = pytest.main(['-k', 'mycode_test',
                       '-o', 'cache_dir=/dbfs/FileStore/',
                       '--junitxml', '/dbfs/FileStore/pytestreport.xml',
                       '-v'
                      ]
                     )
```

This code snippet runs fine on a standard Databricks cluster (with runtime 10.4 LTS and pytest installed) and the results of the unit testing are printed out below the cell.

However, no output is stored at the cache directory or the pointer for the junit xml file.

Questions:

- Are we missing something here?
- Can we assume that it actually generated output at an unknown location because the `pytest.main` did not crash?
- Are the .fuse-mounts within Databricks causing the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that I made some mistakes during my initial setup of the paths in the `pytest.main` command.  I have updated these paths now and they work.

Thus, the snippet below generates the XML and caching files in the databricks FileStore.

Again, this probably only works when you are working within a Databricks Repo with files in repos enabled.

```py
import pytest

retcode = pytest.main(['-k', 'mycode_test',
                       '-o', 'cache_dir=/dbfs/FileStore/',
                       '--junitxml', '/dbfs/FileStore/pytestreport.xml',
                       '-v'
                      ]
                     )
```